# Elasticsearch best_compression is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am parsing Apache access log from `Logstash` and indexing it into a `Elasticsearch` index. I have also indexed `geoip` and `agent` fields.. While indexing I observed elasticsearch index size is `6.7x` bigger than the actual file size (space on disk). So I just want to understand this is the correct behavior or I am doing something wrong here? I am using `Elasticsearch 5.0`, `Logstash 5.0` and `Kibana 5.0` version. I also tried [best_compression](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#_static_index_settings) but it's taking same disk size. Here is the complete observation with configuration file I tried so far.

**My Observations:**

**Use Case 1:**

- [Logstash Conf](https://gist.github.com/roopendra/eca2eb6047c7ce47cf2302820aff3242)
- [Template File](https://gist.github.com/roopendra/d11791bab57cf4e1fe619174d1371df8)

`Apache Log file Size` : 211 MB
`Total number of lines`: 1,000,000
`Index Size`: 1.5 GB
`Observation`: Index is `6.7x` bigger than the file size.

**Use Case 2:**

- [Logstash Conf](https://gist.github.com/roopendra/886447c6de6e413ad1a00e2a5fc0cdfd)
- [Template File](https://gist.github.com/roopendra/cec15bd1dd4a596f6197d44d0704e5fd)

I have found a few solutions to compress elasticsearch index, then I tried it as well.

```
- Disable `_all` fields
- Remove unwanted fields that has been created by `geoip` and `agent` parsing.
- Enable `best_compression` [ index.codec": "best_compression"]
```

`Apache Log file Size` : 211 MB
`Total number of lines`: 1,000,000
`Index Size`: 1.3 GB
`Observation`: Index is `6.16x` bigger than the file size

Log File Format:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2016:02:03:08 -0800] "GET /wp-admin HTTP/1.0" 200 4916 "http://trujillo-carpenter.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 5.01; Trident/5.1)"
```

I found [Logstash + Elasticsearch Storage Experients](https://github.com/jordansissel/experiments/tree/master/elasticsearch/disk) they are saying they have reduced index size from **6.23x** to **1.57x**. But that is pretty old solutions and these solution are no more working in `Elasticsearch 5.0`.

Some more reference I have already tried:
- [Part 2.0: The true story behind Elasticsearch storage requirements](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-storage-the-true-story-2.0)
- https://github.com/elastic/elk-index-size-tests

Is there any better way to optimize the Elasticseach index size when your purpose is only show the visualization on Kibana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this issue due to index settings were not applied to the index. My index name and template name were different. After using the same template name and index name compression is applied properly.

In the below example I was using index name `apache_access_logs` and template name `elk_workshop`.

Sharing corrected template and logstash configuration.

**Logstash.conf**

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "apache_access_logs"
    template => "apache_sizing_2.json"
    template_name => "apache_access_logs" /* it was elk_workshop */
    template_overwrite => true
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
{

    "template": "apache_access_logs", /* it was elk_workshop */
    "settings": {
        "index.refresh_interval": "5s",
        "index.refresh_interval": "30s",
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "number_of_replicas": 0
    },
    ..
}
```

**Reference:** https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html#indices-templates